# how to format a partition of a diskimage?

Tags: mount, partition, disk, disk-image, mkfs

I made an empty binary image file with `fallocate -l 500M sd.img` command and then partitioned it using `gdisk` and now I can see my partitions using `gdisk`:

```
Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-2): 1
Partition GUID code: EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 (Microsoft basic data)
Partition unique GUID: 8B28D50C-C5B5-470D-908D-FF212433AC50
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 43007 (at 21.0 MiB)
Partition size: 40960 sectors (20.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Microsoft basic data'

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-2): 2
Partition GUID code: 69DAD710-2CE4-4E3C-B16C-21A1D49ABED3 (Linux ARM32 root (/))
Partition unique GUID: 8A6F3384-7AC2-448C-BD76-73A772E9E586
First sector: 43008 (at 21.0 MiB)
Last sector: 247807 (at 121.0 MiB)
Partition size: 204800 sectors (100.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Linux ARM32 root (/)'
```

as you can see, I want to format the first partition to FAT32 and the second one to EXT4 for linux root file system.

How can I do this? I know how to format a physical drive with `mkfs.fat` and `mkfs.ext4` but how can I do it for a disk image with 2 separate partitions?

OS: Ubuntu 20 LTS

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Knowing it may help in determining the tools available in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format the partitions contained in the disk image, you can first create block device files for the partitions. With the device files in place you can use `mkfs` as you normally would. When you're finished, then you can remove the device files.

1. Create and list the block device files: `kpartx -av sd.img`
2. Format each partition. Ex. `mkfs.fat /dev/mapper/loop0p1`
3. Remove the block device files: `kpartx -d sd.img`